# Parsing CSV and replacing headers

Tags: objective-c, csv

I'm using CHCSVParser and I'd like to parse through each header value (row index = 0) in a CSV file, and replace each known string with another. Basically, go through the strings in each cell at in row = 0, and if a cell contains a string or another string, replace it with another set one. An example being, if the first cell in the first row contains 1 OR A, replace it with Z. Next, if the second cell in the first row contains 2 OR B, replace it with X, and so on, for a set and known number of columns. This is what I'm trying to do for each cell, but I'm not sure if it will work:

```
        if (row == 0 &&
            ([ObjectAtRow containsObject:@"1"] || [ObjectAtRow containsObject:@"A"])) {
            [ObjectAtRow replaceObjectAtIndex:[[doc objectAtIndex:0] indexOfObject:nil] withObject:@"Z"];
        }
```

Comment: you are not sure if it will work- try it.

Comment: just do it and then NSLog / Debug Step.